# Problem with R console

Tags: r, console, insert, toggle

I have a little problem with my R console recently. When I start R (`"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.8.1\bin\Rgui.exe"`), the cursor immediately starts in INSERT mode (thick state). Then I have to press <kbd>Insert</kbd> and toggle it to normal mode (thin state). As soon as I write a command line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the cursor again toggles to INSERT mode. I don't want to use R with the cursor in INSERT mode, and it's annoying that R always toggles. How can I get R console back to normal?

**EDIT:** Today I realized that when I use the R console as a maximized window, the cursor is always in INSERT mode (thick state). When I unmaximize the window, it automatically gets out of the INSERT mode. The explanations in the first paragraph of my question are still valid as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated R to v2.12.1 and the problem vanished. It seems that there was a bug with that old version of R.

Answer (score 3):

No idea what is causing this but there are things you can try, in order to narrow down the problem.

You need to know whether the problem is caused by that version of R, or all versions of R, or it's a Windows issue, or something else entirely.

Open a command prompt (Start -> Run -> `cmd`), then right-click the title bar and click Properties -> Options.  Is the 'Insert mode' box checked?

Open a different version of R (the latest one, perhaps), and see if you get the same problem.

Comment out your `RProfile.site` file, and see if that affects the situation.

If all else fails, try reinstalling R.

Comment: I controlled cmd options and Insert Mode box was checked. I unchecked it and rerun R, but the problem was still there. I think the problem comes from R itself. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Mehper:  It's a weird problem.  Are you pressing CTRL+O?  That works the same as INS.  Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm not pressing CTRL+O. I guess I'll have to reinstall R. Thanks for your answer, anyway.